# TypeError: Cannot read property 'PORT' of undefined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have tried using other ports such as 8080 but I still get the same error. I am not very experienced with writing server code so I may be doing something wrong. The following is a snippet of my code.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(process.environment.PORT || 52300);

var Player = require('./Classes/Player.js');

console.log('Server Started');

var players = [];
var sockets = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('Connection established');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env), not `process.environment`.

`process.environment` doesn't exist, so the expression is `undefined`. Then, you try to access `PORT` of the undefined value, causing the error that you see.